# angularJS factory not saving $scope state between views

Tags: angularjs

So I must be doing something wrong. I have read the posts on this and most of the suggestions on here suggest setting up a factory to preserve $scope data across views. So I have made a factory to bind $scope data received from option checkboxes, however it is not persistant across views. here is the code in question.. Any ideas?? thanks

my module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial','ui.router']);
```

my factory

```
app.factory('Options', function() {
  var flavors = {};

  flavors.getFlavors = function() {
  return [
  { name: 'Vanilla', wanted: false },
  { name: 'Hazelnut', wanted: false },
  { name: 'Almond', wanted: false },
  { name: 'Caramel', wanted: false }]; 
  };

  return flavors;

});
```

my controller

```
app.controller('OrderFormController', function($scope, Options) {

  $scope.flavors = Options.getFlavors();

});
```

my html option markup

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="flavor in flavors" 
              layout="row">
              <p> {{ flavor.name }} </p>
              <span flex></span>
              <md-checkbox aria-label="flavor.wanted"
                           class="md-accent" 
                           ng-model="flavor.wanted">
              </md-checkbox>
</md-list-item>
```

my html product markup

```
<md-card ng-repeat="item in items.results" 
         ng-controller="OrderFormController">
     <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" 
          class="md-card-image" 
          alt="">
          <md-card-content class="content">
              <h2 class="md-title">{{ item.name }}</h2>
              <h4>{{ item.price | currency }}</h4>
              <p class="container" 
                 ng-class="{show: show}">
                 {{ item.desc}}
              </p>
              <md-button class="md-primary" 
                         ng-click="show = !show"
                         ng-show="!show">
                         <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/unfold-more.svg"></md-icon>
                         <span>Show More</span>
              </md-button>
              <md-button class="md-primary" 
                         ng-click="show = !show"
                         ng-show="show">
                         <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/unfold-less.svg"></md-icon>
                         <span>Show Less</span>
              </md-button>
          </md-card-content>
          <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                         layout-align="end center"
                         ng-show="!addRemove">
                         <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                                    aria-label="Add To Cart" 
                                    ng-click="addRemove = !addRemove;toggleActive(item)"
                                    ng-class="{active:item.active}">
                                    <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/add.svg"></md-icon>
                         </md-button>
        </md-action-bar>
        <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                       layout-align="end center"
                       ng-show="addRemove">
                       <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                                  aria-label="Remove From Cart" 
                                  ng-click="addRemove = !addRemove;toggleActive(item)"
                                  ng-class="{active:item.active}">
                                  <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/remove.svg"></md-icon>
                       </md-button>
        </md-action-bar>
</md-card>
```

items are being parsed from Parse.com database

***EDIT***

So I am having some real problems with this so I created my object class on Parse.com and instead of initializing with the factory it is now being initialized using

```
getOptions();
```

this loads fine and persists the data between different views.. however as mentioned below I now have the issue of all ng-repeat created  child $scope being ofcourse linked to the value in the parent $scope. I was given a good headstart below, but still am not able to create unique $scope based on name or id.. I was going to start a new post but to keep everything on one page i figured i'd just update the post..Since the values of flavors are already initialized i'm not sure i need to reinitialize them within the factory..

Comment: I assume that the controller is set in the routing? What output are you receiving?

Comment: confused... You want to persist checkbox selection across views?

Comment: controller is set in routing and no errors being logged. @ Jonathan Levine

Comment: Yes I would like to persist checkbox selection across views. I have a checkout view that will update price based on these selections @ ABOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory itself may be a singleton, which is what makes it work across views, but the object returned from your `getFlavours()` is a **new instance** of the list every time it is called.  This is why it doesn't seem to record your changes: it does in the first place, but then resets them with the defaults as soon as you try to get them again.

You need to make sure the same instance of the list is returned every time you call that for a given product.

Normally the separation-by-product would be simple because we know that each ng-repeat has its own child scope which could hold a separate instance of the flavors for that product.  But because you want to persist those, which needs a singleton service, you will need to explicitly map them by product within that service.  To use that, your `getFlavors()` will need to take the product name as an argument to uniquely identify it.

```
app.factory('Options', function() {
    // To create a new set of flavors with default settings
    function initFlavors() {
        return [
            { name: 'Vanilla', wanted: false },
            { name: 'Hazelnut', wanted: false },
            { name: 'Almond', wanted: false },
            { name: 'Caramel', wanted: false }
        ];
    }

    var flavorsByProduct = {};

    // Get the flavors for a given product
    flavorsByProduct.getFlavors = function(productName) {
        // On first access for a particular product, create a new set of flavors for it
        if(!flavorsByProduct[productName]) {
            flavorsByProduct[productName] = initFlavors();
        }
        return flavorsByProduct[productName];
    };

    return flavorsByProduct;
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This does preserve the $scope state across views but each product will have the same options value.. i am trying to create an new instance for each product in my ng-repeat directive...I forgot to add that html markup from the product page... If needed i can update my post when i get home..

Comment: The ng-repeat you show there is just enumerating the flavors - so you have another repeat that goes through different products, is that right?  Presumably then each product comes in different flavors, so you're trying to persist the chosen flavor for each separate product ....?

Comment: ok, just seen your added comment about missing product markup - yes if you can show that it would help.  If each product has some kind of identifier/unique-name then it can be done easily enough - I'll wait.

Comment: Yes exactly but when i create new instances for each product (again sorry for not posting the markup) the values are reset to default. Thanks for taking your time to help

Comment: Is the item.name unique, or is there some other identifier?

Comment: item name is unique for each product.. ie. Mocha, Latte, Americano, etc... i have 3 views menu. options, and orders... menu view lists all products, options view lists active products and available options, and order view list all active products with active options and calculates price..

Comment: Ok, updated answer to let it keep separate sets of flavors per product, and also keep those between views.  Thought it would break your controller, but just noticed you create that per repeat, so my answer is actually wrong .....

Comment: ok let me see if i can make it work. i am just grasping the concept of factories and am trying to remove the logic from my bloated controllers... i am using the OrderFormController on all 3 pages right now so i am trying to put all the logic into factories and just have one controller per page that handles all logic using the factory. I really do thank you for your time, so let me see if i can make this work...

Comment: sounds like a good approach yes, I went through the same process myself so i think you're definitely going in the right direction.  Good luck - shout if you need any more.

Answer (score 0):

You nee to change

`$scope.flavors = Options.flavors.getFlavors();` instead of  `$scope.flavors = Options.getFlavors();`

Because your factory returned `flavors` object only. It does not return `getFlavors()` function.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFlavors' of undefined<br>
          at new <anonymous> (index.js:93)<br>
          at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:37)<br>
          at G.instance (angular.min.js:76)<br>
          at angular.min.js:59<br>
          at r (angular.min.js:7)<br>
          at J (angular.min.js:59)<br>
          at g (angular.min.js:52)<br>
          at angular.min.js:51<br>
          at angular.min.js:52<br>
          at k (angular.min.js:57)

Comment: That won't work because .flavors isn't added as an attribute of the factory-made service, and correctly so.  See my answer.